# Small update.. Now cannot download/update

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi

Earlier today I was ssh'ing into my box and discovered that the internal IP had changed from what it was, I decided I wanted to make this static and found a tutorial (kind of) how to:

> ```
> nano /etc/network/interfaces
> ```

And then changed the contents to this:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.0.11
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.0.200
```

(I wanted my IP to be static at this). Now whenever I try to update, or install "git" using:

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

I keep getting the error like so:

```
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy InRelease                                   

Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy InRelease                               

Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release.gpg                                 
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy Release.gpg                             
Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Reading package lists... Done                 
W: Failed to fetch      
http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch 
http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/wheezy/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch   
http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Temporary 
failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'

W: Failed to fetch 
http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  
Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
```

I am connected to the internet, and this only seems to be happening since I updated the particular file.

UPDATE:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.200   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0


eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:87:59:47  
          inet addr:192.168.0.11  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4707 errors:0 dropped:50 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:334663 (326.8 KiB)  TX bytes:390376 (381.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:67655 (66.0 KiB)  TX bytes:67655 (66.0 KiB)
```

Comment: Can you post output of `netstat -rn` and `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: @Karlson Thank you for the reply. I have updated my o/p to what you asked for

Comment: You'd be better off just configuring your router to always allocate the same IP to this machine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your IP and gateway are properly configured, your DNS nameservers are not. They can be configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`, in the following format:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Another option is to install the resolvconf package and add the following to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then restart the interface for the changes to take affect:

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

Comment: Thanks :) In /etc/resolv.conf I have "nameserver 194.168.4.100" repeated, so shall I replace these with: nameserver 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @phorce that's not the problem if `194.168.4.100` is a valid nameserver. Can you ping it? You can definitely try `8.8.8.8`, which is google's resolver.

Comment: I can ping it, yes. Is there any way that I could go back to how it was before? I.e. replace the lines in "/etc/network/interfaces" and then have my router static the IP for this device? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `194.168.4.100` is a DNS server?  When I did lookup for NS records for this IP I got 4 completely different servers.

Comment: the address `194.168.4.100` you wrote as DNS is probably mean to be `192.168.4.100` instead. It's a private subnet (`192.168.4.x`) and .100 can be your local router / DNS (as is in some ADSL gateways-router setup). If it's the case, check your router IP.